# Привязка обработчика события клика к таймеру по классу не срабатывает

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Имеется код:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.slide-225').onclick = function() {
  var timer_metaslider_206 = function() {
    var slider = !window.jQuery ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_206, 100) : !jQuery.isReady ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_206, 1) : metaslider_206(window.jQuery);
  };
  timer_metaslider_206();
};
```

Нужно привязать клик к таймеру по классу, но скрипт не срабатывает и в консоль ошибку не выводит. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавлен  `EventListener`, чтоб отлавливать клик.

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('slides')[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
      $('.flex-next').flexslider("next");
    })
```

Comment: Почему бы не описать в ответе что поменялось и почему?

Comment: Увы, но ничего не поменялось и в консоли ошибку не вывел.

Comment: не успел, щас добавлю

Comment: @Webdev96 timer_metaslider_206 это что?

Comment: timer_metaslider_206 - это переменная которую я объявил для таймера. Увы но добавление EventListener-a не помогло.

Comment: где код? можете показать эту функцию

Comment: @L.Vadim 

    `document.getElementsByClassName('slide-225')[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var timer_metaslider_206 = function() {
        var slider = !window.jQuery ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_206, 100) : !jQuery.isReady ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_206, 1) : metaslider_206(window.jQuery);
    };
    timer_metaslider_206();
    })`

Comment: timer_metaslider_206() - эту функцию вложите в вопрос

Comment: @L.Vadim Извините я вас не совсем понял. Я показал вам весь скрипт что был. Для прояснения вопроса наверное мне стоит разъяснить что мне надо. Есть слайдер - задача - клик по img с классом - и переход на другую img. Реализовать это я хочу с помощью привязки клика к таймеру - что надеюсь сработает.

Comment: Так функции таймера не существует? Можете загрузить весь код со сдайдером. Я сделаю таймер

Comment: @L.Vadim давайте обговорим все в личке - https://vk.com/id229303335 - напишите мне пожалуйста в вк и я вам уже там скину весь код.

Comment: @L.Vadim Но если вас нет в вк то вот ссылка на сам скрипт слайдера. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw86uq8VfcgfMzZhaE9JTmM1SDg

Answer (score 0):

Так не подойдет?:

```
$('.class').click(function(){
    setTimeout(timer,2000);
});


function timer(){

}
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Отпишусь если поможет

Comment: Нет, увы но не помогло(